# roslaunch: KeyError: 'file'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
I got a ROS package, but when I type `roslaunch arm_launch.launch` I got this error and don't know how to deal with it ...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ roslaunch launch/arm_launch.launch
logging to /home/pi/.ros/log/d94a9972-1009-11ec-a551-c5d9d944afff/roslaunch-raspberrypi-1202.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 347, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 305, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 254, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 157, in _load_config
    roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 461, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, argv=args, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 761, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 733, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 699, in _recurse_load
    val = self._include_tag(tag, context, ros_config, default_machine, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 96, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 596, in _include_tag
    inc_filename = self.resolve_args(tag.attributes['file'].value, context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    return self._attrs[attname_or_tuple]
KeyError: 'file'
```

My launch file, arm_launch.launch look like that :

```
<launch>
  <include name="$(find braccio_controller)/launch.launch"/>
  <include name="$(find detection)/launch.launch"/>
</launch>
```

If you need anything else let me know,
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386218/roslaunch:-keyerror:-%27file%27/) by [El_French](https://answers.ros.org/users/84351/el_french/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is here:

> ```
> <include name="$(find braccio_controller)/launch.launch"/>
> ```

The correct way to `include` another `.launch` file is:

```
<include file="..." />
```

The name of the attribute should be `file`, not `name`.

See also [wiki/roslaunch/XML/include](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [El_French](https://answers.ros.org/users/84351/el_french/) on 2021-09-10**:
Thanks for your answer I don't have the error anymore.
But I have a new one ...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ roslaunch launch/arm_launch.launch
... logging to /home/pi/.ros/log/3665a23c-1253-11ec-bf58-b827eb6b0003/roslaunch-raspberrypi-8569.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Resource not found: braccio_controller
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/noetic/share
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Do you what's the new problem ?
I also changed my launched file according to the link you send.

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find braccio_controller)/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/braccio_controller/braccio_controller.launch"/>
  <include file="$(find detection)//home/pi/catkin_ws/src/detection/detection_launch.launch"/>
</launch>
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-10**:
Please do not post follow-up questions as comments to answers. That's not how ROS Answers works.

Similar to Stack Overflow, Askbot is a Q&A forum, which works best with a 1-to-1 ratio of questions and answers.

If your original problem was solved, indicate that by clicking the check mark (✓) to the left of the answer. It should turn green.

Then post a new question describing your new problem, possibly mentioning your previous one (to keep things connected). But only post new questions if you've determined there isn't already an existing Q&A discussing your problem (tip: use Google to search, instead of the built-in search. Append `site:answers.ros.org` to your query string).